# Serialized AJAX $_POST is not empty but single $_REQUEST is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm making an AJAX Call like this:

```
$( "#submit_jobs_preview" ).click(function(e) {
    var postData = $('#new_job_form').serialize();
    var formURL = "ajax.xxx.php";
    
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: formURL,
    data: {submit_jobs_preview: postData },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }   
    });     
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default actio
});
```

In php i echo:

```
echo $_POST['submit_jobs_preview'];
```

**This $_POST shows all values i put in my form correctly like this:**

```
new_job_city=Berlin&new_job_name=Manager etc.
```

But if i want a single $_REQUEST from this $_POST like this:

```
 if($_POST['submit_jobs_preview']){
    echo $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['new_job_city']);
 }
```

the alert is empty.

Why is that?

**UPDATE**

Full return of data:

```
XHR Loaded (autocomplete.php - 200 OK - 105.99994659423828ms - 354B) VM2106:3
new_job_city=Halle&new_job_job=Flugbegleiter&new_job_other_job=&job_zielgruppe=Auszubildende&new_job_phone=4921663965439&new_job_email=kleefeld%40dsc-medien.de&new_job_detailhead=F%C3%BCr+unser+zentrales+Marketing+mit+Sitz+in+der+Hauptverwaltung+in+der+City+von+D%C3%BCsseldorf+suchen+wir+zum+n%C3%A4chstm%C3%B6glichen+Termin+eine%2Fn&new_job_time=Vollzeit&teilzeit_std=&new_job_tasks=&new_job_profile=&new_job_advantage=&new_job_creatorId=1&new_job_creationDate=1390569795&new_job_scope=Airport+Service&new_job_niederlassung=7&new_job_active=0
```

Comment: will you post all post parameters of ajax request? OR paste print_r($_POST) here

Comment: i don't think you can access this way.

Comment: Ok.Why don't you use $_POST['new_job_city']; instead of $_REQUEST?

Comment: `serialize` creates a _string_ value, and by putting that into an object while sending it you also only get one string value server-side. Pass the result of `serialize` as `data` directly in your AJAX call, then you will get individual POST parameters named according to the form fields.

Comment: @CBroe how to do that? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `{submit_jobs_preview: postData }` if it is not necessary. I will give you another hint. Use following ajax;

```
$( "#submit_jobs_preview" ).click(function(e) {
    var postData = $('#new_job_form').serialize();
    var formURL = "ajax.xxx.php";

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: formURL,
    data: postData,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }   
    });     
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default actio
});
```

and on php side;

```
if($_POST['new_job_city']){
    echo $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['new_job_city']);
}
```

In this case you can use field names directly.

**Another hint:**

You can put a hidden value on your form like,

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit_jobs_preview" value="true"/>
```

and js side will be same as above in my answer, and in php side you can check like;

```
if($_POST['submit_jobs_preview']){
    echo $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['new_job_city']);
}
```

As you can see, you can send your post value as hidden field and make your check

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that works. But i'm posting a form with multiple values. Is it possible to do that with one if clause as i did in my post? Or do i have to make a if clause for each value?

Comment: Nope, I put `if($_POST['new_job_city'])` for being sure about that form submitted. You will get all the form values on php side. I will added another hint, please check

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['submit_jobs_preview'] holds a string and nothing else so you just can't access it that way. Use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to unserialize $_POST['submit_jobs_preview']. That way you can access its properties.

```
$_POST['submit_jobs_preview']['new_job_city']
```

Comment: With that i get "n" as result. cO